# Pushing code to github while ssh'd into another machine

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am working remote and ssh'd into a work machine. I am trying to push code to github from my remote connection, but it keeps asking for my username and password. I know github changed the way they authenticate users, but both machines have working ssh-keys for github.

While ssh'd into machine A I ran

```
ssh git@github.com
```

and get back

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi jasperwreed! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

but then I try and run git push and it asks for my username and password.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you run `ssh git@github.com`, you're trying to ssh into githubs server, which they don't allow. If you want to push code, use `git push`, just like you would on your local machine (assuming that you've installed git on the remote computer)

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but then I try and run git push and it asks for my username and password.

This is because you have a "remote" that uses the `https` URL rather than a `ssh` one. To verify this, do `git remote -v`. You will probably see output something like

```
origin https://github.com/myUser/myRepo.git
```

Note that this is using a HTTPS URL for the remote. To change this to use `ssh` instead

1. Open your repository in the browser
2. Click on the "Code" button on the right side above the directory listing
3. Select the SSH tab
4. Click the copy to clipboard button
5. Now open your terminal and type `git remote set-url origin`
6. Paste the URL and hit enter.

Now you will be able to use commands like `git push` and `git fetch` using SSH.

Comment: This worked perfectly, than you very much!!